# Symfony 3 Security for Signup popup

Tags: forms, symfony, security, popup

I got a website with a popup sign up, so when people want to sign or log in they click in the main design on a button and there are a popup who are display.

My problem here is because i got a lot of controller who need to be log in for use and i use this command for redirect user when they aren't connect:

```
    /**
   * @Security("has_role('ROLE_USER')")
   */
```

but it's redirect user to the login page

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            login_path:             fos_user_security_login 
            check_path:             fos_user_security_check
```

I would like to change that and just open my popup when they try to go somewhere who need User Access and not going to a new page.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do this in any of my webapps. In my case I mark in all the links that need to be logged in to access for example with a class or a data atributte:

```
<a href="/must-logged-url" data-must-be-logged>Private area</a>
```

I create a global javascript variable in my base twig:

```
{% if app.user %}
    User.isLogged = true
{% else %}
    User.isLogged = false
{% endif %}
```

And with jQuery i intercept the attemp to access to a private area

```
$('a[data-must-be-logged]').click(function(e) {
  if (User.isLogged) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#login-modal').modal('show');
  }
});
```

I write this by memory and maybe can contain some errors but I hope this can help you